# Simple SQL CASE Question - from WHERE to CASE function

Tags: sql, case, where-clause

Sorry for the noob question, new to SQL here and would appreciate help :)

I have this SQL query:

```
select * from nobel_win 
where (subject = 'Physiology' and year < 1971) 
and (subject = 'Peace' and year => 1974)
```

Will I have the same result if I use this query? (Am I applying the case function correctly here?) If not, can someone help me fix the query below, if possible?

```
select * 
(case when subject = 'Physiology' and year < 1971 end),
(case when subject = 'Peace' and year => 1974 end),
from nobel_win
```

*****EDIT****

The original query actually went like this, and I tried to shorten the UNION by doing WHERE (refer to first code block). Can someone correct my first code block so that it'll display the same output? Thanks a bunch :(

```
(select * from nobel_win
where subject = 'Physiology' and year < 1971)
UNION
(select * from nobel_win
where subject = 'Peace' and year => 1974)
```

Comment: No, the first query will return no results at all and the second query will not run because it has syntax errors.

Comment: If you try it yourself,you will find the answer quickly **No**,even if the second has not syntax error,the resultset of second is larger than first one

Comment: No. Where is a filter to exclude data. Case when is to decode something but it will fetch all data without any exclude. So qn is what do you want? Filttered data or all data with decode logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the first version, or a slight modification of it, is likely what you want here:

```
SELECT *
FROM nobel_win 
WHERE
    subject = 'Physiology' AND year < 1971 OR
    subject = 'Peace' AND year >= 1974;
```

Note that I have ORed the two conditions together, since it is impossible for a single record to belong to more than one subject (or year).  Note that `CASE` expressions are not for handling boolean logic, but rather they output scalar values based on certain logic.

Comment: Got this! Although having 'OR' will just give me one of the two, am I right? I actually want to show both results. I appended my post to contain the original UNION query I tried to shorten

Comment: My answer is logically equivalent to the union query you wrote.  Note that you could also have used `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`, for slightly better performance.

Comment: Wow I have so much SQL learning to do.. thanks so much :)

Comment: @tim, You have to use "(" for OR condition otherwise this where condition working wrong.

Comment: @B.Muthamizhselvi Not true at all.  AND has higher precedence than OR, so the parentheses you suggest putting in are logically already there.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it like that, it can be done like this, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM nobel_win
WHERE 1 = 
    CASE
        WHEN subject = 'Physiology' AND year < 1971 THEN 1
        WHEN subject = 'Peace' AND year >= 1974 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query

First Query

```
SELECT *
FROM nobel_win 
WHERE
(subject = 'Physiology' AND year < 1971)
OR (subject = 'Peace' AND year >= 1974);
```

Second query

Its syntax error. In your case statement "Then" is missing.